# How to show postal code field in Stripe element

Tags: stripe-payments, postal-code, stripes

I am trying to integrate Stripe payments into my project, but it seems that Stripe's payment element doesn't show the postal code field. Is there a way to display that field?

Here is my code

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

<script>
const stripe = Stripe('PUBLIC_KEY');

const elements = stripe.elements({
                     clientSecret: clientSecret,
                     theme: 'stripe',
                 });

const element = elements.create("payment");

element.mount('#card-stripe');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to 'force-display' fields with the `payment` element.

Using the `fields` param won't help - you have two values: `auto` and `never`. There is no `always` value. `auto` will only conditionally show the field.

Concretely, the `payment` element will show the postal code field only if the card BIN matches a card that requires postal code collection - e.g. US or GB cards. You can also witness this by changing the country field on the element.

If you want to always display and collect a postal code, your options are to create the postal code element yourself (in which case you would omit it from the `payment` element with `never`), or use an `address` element in conjunction with your `payment` element:
https://stripe.com/docs/elements/address-element

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are right. I tried VNP to the US and the postal code actually appeared

Answer (score 1):

You can specify what billing fields you want to display by passing this property:
https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_payment_element#payment_element_create-options-fields-billingDetails

You are looking at this field in particular in order to display the postal code:

https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_payment_element#payment_element_create-options-fields-billingDetails-address-postalCode

```
const paymentElement = elements.create("payment", {
        fields: {
            billingDetails: {
                name: 'auto',
                email: 'auto',
                address: {
                    postalCode: 'auto'
                }
            },
        }
    });
```